# How to draw feasible set in Latex with indifference curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, graphics, diagrams, draw

[image]

Hi
I want to draw this in LaTex but i have not succeded in drawing the feasible set or the indifference curve. I have very litlle experience with LaTex but I can tell from other questions that I should use tikzpicture or pgfplot, but I just cant seem to get the code right.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome. This is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\sffamily,scale=1.5]
 \draw (0,3.5) node[left]{$c_2$} -- (0,0) node[below left] {$0$} 
  -- (3.5,0) node[below right]{$c_1$};
 \draw plot[domain=1:3,smooth] (\x,3/\x-1/2);
 \draw (0,1) node[left]{$y_2$} -| node[pos=0.25,below=3mm] {Feasible set}
  (2,0) node[below]{$y_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a dragon :-) with TikZ-pgf. I've always been impressed by your speed.

Comment: @Sebastiano Grazie!

Comment: What are your answers with the downvotes, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano No, I am not asking for compensation, just to tell you you are not alone. ;-)

Comment: Check if they're zinc, copper or ahahaah aluminum.